# How could i Create a process with hiding the process window (from the task bar) in winXP? with CreateProcess function?

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder, createprocess

```
 /* CreateProcess initialization */
 STARTUPINFO si;
 PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

 memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
 memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(pi));
 si.cb = sizeof(si);

 long ret;
 // si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
 // hide process window.... // run in background..

 si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
 si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

 if (!CreateProcess(0, exe,
        0, 0, 1, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0, 0, &si, &pi)) {
    return;
 }
 //int prez = WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

 //CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can attempt to set the `dwFlags` member of your [`STARTUPINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx) structure to `STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` and the `wShowWindow` member to `SW_HIDE`.

This will make `CreateProcess()` pass 0 as the `nCmdShow` parameter of [`WinMain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633559(v=vs.85).aspx).  However, not all Windows application are well behaved and use this value to the initial call to `ShowWindow()`.

Comment: How would this stop the window appearing in the task bar? It may start the app with the main window minimised, but surely it would still appear in the task bar?

Comment: ShowWindow() will actually ignore the value you pass the first time it is called and use STARTUPINFO instead (This is documented) to help with this exact issue.

Comment: @David: last time I checked, `SW_HIDE` does not minimize the window, but hide it completely, and it doesn't appear in the task bar.

Comment: é I would appear to be talking a load of nonsense and I stand corrected. Indeed I can even locate code that I wrote in the past year which uses `SW_HIDE` for exactly this purpose!!  However, in that case it is a console app and I have a feeling that many GUI apps would not listen to this instruction. But perhaps I'm wrong again and should stop flogging this particular dead horse!

Answer (score 0):

It's not you, the creator of the new process, that registers the new process into the task bar. It's the new process that creates a top-level window that decides whether or not to be in the taskbar. This decision is based on the extended style of that top-level window, which is determined by the new process.

In other words, you'd have to poke at the top-level window in this other process in order to do this.

Comment: WS_EX_APPWINDOW is not required for a window to be visible in the taskbar, a visible top level non-toolbar window with basic chrome (caption,border etc) gets a taskbar button even without that style...

Comment: @Anders Thank you for that clarification. The main sense of my answer remains correct though, wouldn't you say?

Comment: @Anders I've re-read the topic on extended window styles. Including `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` appears to exclude your top-level window from the taskbar. Anyway, I'm confused now as to exactly what you do to appear in the taskbar, but I'm sure it's determined by the top-level window styles and not the call to CreateProcess.

Comment: @David Heffernan: To put it another way, WS_EX_APPWINDOW is used to force a taskbar button even if the HWND normally would not have one (It has WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW or is a owned window etc)

Comment: @Anders OK, I think I'm there now!! Thanks.

Comment: The essense of this answer is that the properties of a window determines its taskbar-visibility. There is nothing an outside observer can do to interfere unless the program provides some means to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the window associated with the started process (see `FindWindow` and `EnumWindows`), and call `ShowWindow` function with `SW_HIDE`. Alternatively you can modify the extended style of the window by removing `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` and adding `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW`.

The simplest way is still to use STARTUPINFO as described in the first answer, if the started process respects the setting.